# Using RSpec & Capybara to test Rails' created_at (TimeWithZone)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, rspec

Looking for best practice in testing the rendering of a TimeWithZone object in a Rails app.

This fails because, at least I *think* it's because we pass a date when we create the object and it's stored in the DB as `2014-01-10T00:00:00.000Z`.

Yet when rendered

But what is being tested is the rendered page where

```
let(:attachment) { create :attachment, created_at: '2014-01-10' }

    background do
      user.article.attachments << [attachment]
      stub_image_convert(new_file[:url])
      stub_request(:put, new_file[:s3_request])

      visit article_path(user.article, as: user)
    end

    scenario 'uploaded files are added to the list' do
      expect(page).to have_css '.attachment-item', count: 1
      within file_group_selector(position: 1) do
        upload_date_present 'January 10, 2014'
        file_previews_present count: 1
      end
    ...
 ...
```

helper:

```
  def upload_date_present(date)
    expect(page).to have_css 'grouped-attachments .group-title', text: date
  end
```

and it's ultimately displayed on page by [momentJS](https://momentjs.com) (javascript/Angular) which renders the date:

```
  newAttachment.groupDate = moment().format('LL')
```

and fails because of what I assume must be a localized timezone adjustment:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_text 'January 10th, 2014'
   expected to find text "January 10th, 2014" in "John Snow First comment message January 9th, 2014"
```

How should we be testing this? FWIW Timecop doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`created_at` expects a full date with time, not just a date. I guess Rails parses your string date as a DateTime with 00:00:00 as time. Try creating a proper DateTime object with the correct timezone and pass that as the value. That way you leave nothing to the under the hood magic that Rails does.